# transferring tables to extranl database server

Tags: mysql

I have almost 37 MB table data what I want to export to live Database server in shared environment.

I have access to extrenal database through phpmyadmin. What will be the best way to transfer this table.

Comment: Dump table and data with phpmyadmin and load with phpmyadmin also. You may commit batches of records. For example 1000 records at a time

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the mysqldump command on the remote database to extract the SQL statements of the database required.
2. copy the extracted file to your local system
3. execute the sql file which will create the database in the local system

Answer (score 0):

There are many available tools on the internet. The one I am using to transfer data from one server to another is **[Navicat Premium](http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_premium/premium_overview.html)**. It has the ability to copy database from one server to another server, or even from `MySQL` to `SQL Server`.

or simply use **[mysqldbcopy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/mysqldbcopy.html)**

This utility copies a database on a source server to a database on a destination server. If the source and destination servers are different, the database names can be the same or different. If the source and destination servers are the same, the database names must be different.

The utility accepts one or more database pairs on the command line. To name a database pair, use **db_name:new_db_name** syntax to specify the source and destination names explicitly. If the source and destination database names are the same, **db_name** can be used as shorthand for **db_name:db_name**.